# How to bind image to mahapps icon packs?

Tags: wpf, image, binding, icons

How to achieve this either in .XAML or programmatically?

```
<Image>
 <!--<iconPacks:PackIconMaterial Kind="{Binding Status}"/>-->
 </Image>
```

Answer (score 3):

I had same problem.

I am using a package allows only `System.Windows.Controls.Image`

I solved from C# side.

Lets create a Mahapps Icon

```
PackIconFontAwesome icon  = new PackIconFontAwesome();
icon.Kind = PackIconFontAwesomeKind.AddressBook;
```

And convert to `Geometry`

```
Geometry geo = Geometry.Parse(icon.Data);
GeometryDrawing gd = new GeometryDrawing();
gd.Geometry = geo;
gd.Brush = icon.BorderBrush;
gd.Pen = new Pen(Brushes.White, 100);
```

`icon.Data` gives XAML Path of icon [Path Markup Syntax](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752293(v=vs.110).aspx)

Now we can convert to `Image`  [How to: Use a Drawing as an Image Source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753308(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
DrawingImage geoImage = new DrawingImage(gd);
geoImage.Freeze();
Image img = new Image();
img.Source = geoImage;
```

Now you can bind where ever you want.

Answer (score 3):

Using a Converter is the easiest way of doing this (expanded on tetralobita's answer) but I didn't see the need to create a bunch of template classes so here is a working version using just one Converter:

```
namespace MyProject.Converters
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Converts a <see cref="PackIcon{TKind}" /> to an DrawingImage.
    /// Use the ConverterParameter to pass a Brush.
    /// </summary>
    public class PackIconToImageConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the thickness to draw the icon with.
        /// </summary>
        public double Thickness { get; set; } = 0.25;

        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            GeometryDrawing geoDrawing = new GeometryDrawing();

            geoDrawing.Brush = parameter as Brush ?? Brushes.Black;
            geoDrawing.Pen = new Pen(geoDrawing.Brush, Thickness);

            if (value is PackIconFontAwesome)
                geoDrawing.Geometry = Geometry.Parse((value as PackIcon<PackIconFontAwesomeKind>).Data);
            else if (value is PackIconMaterial)
                geoDrawing.Geometry = Geometry.Parse((value as PackIcon<PackIconMaterialKind>).Data);
            else if (value is PackIconMaterialLight)
                geoDrawing.Geometry = Geometry.Parse((value as PackIcon<PackIconEntypoKind>).Data);
            else if (value is PackIconModern)
                geoDrawing.Geometry = Geometry.Parse((value as PackIcon<PackIconMaterialLightKind>).Data);
            else if (value is PackIconEntypo)
                geoDrawing.Geometry = Geometry.Parse((value as PackIcon<PackIconEntypoKind>).Data);
            else if (value is PackIconOcticons)
                geoDrawing.Geometry = Geometry.Parse((value as PackIcon<PackIconOcticonsKind>).Data);

            var drawingGroup = new DrawingGroup { Children = { geoDrawing }, Transform = new ScaleTransform(1, -1) };

            return new DrawingImage { Drawing = drawingGroup };
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

And then to use the Converter:

Add the Namespace to your .xaml file:

```
xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:MyProject.Converters"
```

Then to Display the Icon as an Image:

```
<Image Source="{Binding Source={icons:PackIconMaterial sitemap},
               Converter={converters:PackIconToImageConverter},
               ConverterParameter={StaticResource TextBrush}}"/>
```

Or to use a Dependency Property as in a UserControl or Custom Control add the following to your Control:

```
/// <summary>
/// Identifies the <see cref="Icon"/> dependency property.
/// </summary>
public static readonly DependencyProperty IconProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(Icon), typeof(object), typeof(MyControl), new PropertyMetadata(null));

/// <summary>
/// Gets or sets a value that specifies an user specific object which can be used as icon.
/// </summary>
public object Icon {
   get { return GetValue(IconProperty); }
   set { SetValue(IconProperty, value); }
}
```

Then Bind to the Property, in your template add:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="MyControlTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type local:MyControl}">

    <Image Source="{TemplateBinding Icon,
                   Converter={StaticResource IconPackConverter}, 
                   ConverterParameter={StaticResource TextBrush}}" />

</ControlTemplate>
```

Answer (score 3):

Maybe I'm a little too late but I was working on this.
I think that sometimes the solution could be way easier
Create this xmlns on your xaml page:

```
xmlns:iconPacks="http://metro.mahapps.com/winfx/xaml/iconpacks"
```

and then...

```
<Image Source="{Binding Source={iconPacks:BootstrapIconsImage Kind=Upload}}"/>
```

and the image will show up.

Enjoy coding

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need this in an image? The icons are SVG assets rendered as a font in a custom control. Unless you're trying to do something particularly advanced, you can simply remove the `<Image>` tags and use the `<iconPacks:PackIconMaterial />` control directly as shown [here](https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro.IconPacks).

Comment: I want to use it as SVG asset rendered in / embedded in any control instead of in it's own custom control. Is it designed or can it be used for this purpose? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is a better solution which I found it on github, more explanation about the code is [here](https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro.IconPacks/issues/39#issuecomment-292471112)

You can convert it via a converter and use it in `XAML` like this

```
ImageSource="{Binding Source={x:Static 
iconPacks:PackIconEntypoKind.AddToList}, Converter=
{converters:PackIconEntypoImageSourceConverter}, ConverterParameter=
{StaticResource TextBrush}}"
```

Converter code is

```
/// <summary>
/// Converts a <see cref="PackIcon{TKind}" /> to an ImageSource.
/// Use the ConverterParameter to pass a Brush.
/// </summary>
public abstract class PackIconImageSourceConverterBase<TKind> : MarkupExtension, IValueConverter
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the thickness to draw the icon with.
    /// </summary>
    public double Thickness { get; set; } = 0.25;

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (!(value is TKind))
            return null;

        var foregroundBrush = parameter as Brush ?? Brushes.Black;
        return CreateImageSource(value, foregroundBrush, Thickness);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        return this;
    }

    protected abstract ImageSource CreateImageSource(object value, Brush foregroundBrush, double penThickness);
}

/// <summary>
/// Converts a <see cref="PackIcon{TKind}" /> to an ImageSource.
/// Use the ConverterParameter to pass a Brush.
/// </summary>
public class PackIconImageSourceConverter : MarkupExtension, IValueConverter
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the thickness to draw the icon with.
    /// </summary>
    public double Thickness { get; set; } = 0.25;

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is null)
            return null;

        if (value is PackIconFontAwesomeKind)
            return new PackIconFontAwesomeImageSourceConverter { Thickness = Thickness }.Convert(value, targetType, parameter, culture);
        if (value is PackIconMaterialKind)
            return new PackIconMaterialImageSourceConverter { Thickness = Thickness }.Convert(value, targetType, parameter, culture);
        if (value is PackIconMaterialLightKind)
            return new PackIconMaterialLightImageSourceConverter { Thickness = Thickness }.Convert(value, targetType, parameter, culture);
        if (value is PackIconModernKind)
            return new PackIconModernImageSourceConverter { Thickness = Thickness }.Convert(value, targetType, parameter, culture);
        if (value is PackIconEntypoKind)
            return new PackIconEntypoImageSourceConverter { Thickness = Thickness }.Convert(value, targetType, parameter, culture);
        if (value is PackIconOcticonsKind)
            return new PackIconOcticonsImageSourceConverter { Thickness = Thickness }.Convert(value, targetType, parameter, culture);

        return null;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        return this;
    }
}

public class PackIconEntypoImageSourceConverter : PackIconImageSourceConverterBase<PackIconEntypoKind>
{
    protected override ImageSource CreateImageSource(object value, Brush foregroundBrush, double penThickness)
    {
        var packIcon = new PackIconEntypo { Kind = (PackIconEntypoKind)value };

        var geometryDrawing = new GeometryDrawing
        {
            Geometry = Geometry.Parse(packIcon.Data),
            Brush = foregroundBrush,
            Pen = new Pen(foregroundBrush, penThickness)
        };

        var drawingGroup = new DrawingGroup { Children = { geometryDrawing }, Transform = new ScaleTransform(1, -1) };

        return new DrawingImage { Drawing = drawingGroup };
    }
}

public class PackIconFontAwesomeImageSourceConverter : PackIconImageSourceConverterBase<PackIconFontAwesomeKind>
{
    protected override ImageSource CreateImageSource(object value, Brush foregroundBrush, double penThickness)
    {
        var packIcon = new PackIconFontAwesome { Kind = (PackIconFontAwesomeKind)value };

        var geometryDrawing = new GeometryDrawing
        {
            Geometry = Geometry.Parse(packIcon.Data),
            Brush = foregroundBrush,
            Pen = new Pen(foregroundBrush, penThickness)
        };

        var drawingGroup = new DrawingGroup { Children = { geometryDrawing }, Transform = new ScaleTransform(1, -1) };

        return new DrawingImage { Drawing = drawingGroup };
    }
}

public class PackIconMaterialImageSourceConverter : PackIconImageSourceConverterBase<PackIconMaterialKind>
{
    protected override ImageSource CreateImageSource(object value, Brush foregroundBrush, double penThickness)
    {
        var packIcon = new PackIconMaterial { Kind = (PackIconMaterialKind)value };

        var geometryDrawing = new GeometryDrawing
        {
            Geometry = Geometry.Parse(packIcon.Data),
            Brush = foregroundBrush,
            Pen = new Pen(foregroundBrush, penThickness)
        };

        var drawingGroup = new DrawingGroup { Children = { geometryDrawing } };

        return new DrawingImage { Drawing = drawingGroup };
    }
}

public class PackIconMaterialLightImageSourceConverter : PackIconImageSourceConverterBase<PackIconMaterialLightKind>
{
    protected override ImageSource CreateImageSource(object value, Brush foregroundBrush, double penThickness)
    {
        var packIcon = new PackIconMaterialLight { Kind = (PackIconMaterialLightKind)value };

        var geometryDrawing = new GeometryDrawing
        {
            Geometry = Geometry.Parse(packIcon.Data),
            Brush = foregroundBrush,
            Pen = new Pen(foregroundBrush, penThickness)
        };

        var drawingGroup = new DrawingGroup { Children = { geometryDrawing } };

        return new DrawingImage { Drawing = drawingGroup };
    }
}

public class PackIconModernImageSourceConverter : PackIconImageSourceConverterBase<PackIconModernKind>
{
    protected override ImageSource CreateImageSource(object value, Brush foregroundBrush, double penThickness)
    {
        var packIcon = new PackIconModern { Kind = (PackIconModernKind)value };

        var geometryDrawing = new GeometryDrawing
        {
            Geometry = Geometry.Parse(packIcon.Data),
            Brush = foregroundBrush,
            Pen = new Pen(foregroundBrush, penThickness)
        };

        var drawingGroup = new DrawingGroup { Children = { geometryDrawing } };

        return new DrawingImage { Drawing = drawingGroup };
    }
}

public class PackIconOcticonsImageSourceConverter : PackIconImageSourceConverterBase<PackIconOcticonsKind>
{
    protected override ImageSource CreateImageSource(object value, Brush foregroundBrush, double penThickness)
    {
        var packIcon = new PackIconOcticons { Kind = (PackIconOcticonsKind)value };

        var geometryDrawing = new GeometryDrawing
        {
            Geometry = Geometry.Parse(packIcon.Data),
            Brush = foregroundBrush,
            Pen = new Pen(foregroundBrush, penThickness)
        };

        var drawingGroup = new DrawingGroup { Children = { geometryDrawing } };

        return new DrawingImage { Drawing = drawingGroup };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have been successfully using the following XAML-only solution:

```
<ContentControl Margin="10,2" Background="Blue" Foreground="White" 
                Content="{iconPacks:Material Kind=GestureTap}"
                ToolTip="This is a tooltip"
                IsEnabled="{Binding ShouldThisBeEnabled}"
                Visibility="{Binding ShouldThisBeVisible, Converter={StaticResource VisibilityFromBool}}" />
```